# How to find the maximum length of string of particular fontsize that can come in a CEDIT rectangle in MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to find out the maximum fontsize for a particular string that can come in a CEDIT Rectangle in MFC.

How I want is :

```
int maxFontSizeThatCanResideInCedit(string text){
    do something
    return fontSize;
}
```

What I am thinking is if somehow I can find the pixel length/width and compare string with every font.
I am new in MFC so i am unaware how to do it?
Currently I am stuck with this issue?

Comment: That's failing to even understand the basics of the problem domain. It's quite obvious that the strings "WWW" and "iii" have very different space requirements, even though both have the same `stringLength`. At a minimum your function needs the following arguments: **Actual** character string, font(s) to use, and a device context.

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry for inconvenience. I should have given string rather than stringsize. Thanks for pointing out. With string we can calculate each chars width. Please help me in finding the solution. I have also edited the question/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Won't code the answer, but will talk through it...

First, an edit control will have a font. First thing you have to know is what font name and font size are going to be used for the edit control.

You might want to default to `GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)` or not. But, it might be a good place to start.

You can create an information context.

```
CDC ic;
ic.CreateIC("display", 0, 0, 0); // from memory, so check
```

From there you can select the font into the ic. (Remember to reset it to the original before the desctructor is called)

Once you have the ic, you want to get the text metrics;

```
TEXMETRIC tm;
ic.GetTextMetrics(&tm);

int nMaxCharWidth = tm.tmMaxCharWidth;
```

So that is the max width for any character in the font. If you want 8 characters, the width is `8*nMaxCharWidth`.

However, maybe you want to use the average?

```
int nAveCharWidth = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
```

Then the width would be `nDesiredChars*nAveCharWidth` where nDesiredChars... well figure it out.

[EDIT]

Forgot about the height. Look at `TEXTMETRIC` structure. It has height members. You can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

`DrawText` with your string with `DT_CALCRECT` to calculate rectangle and `DT_EDITCONTROL` to apply Edit Control behavior.

Should select the font in Device Context first.

Note that string length is not enough, since many fonts are not fixed widths.